# Push UITableView down when adding subview to UINavigationBar

Tags: swift, xcode, uitableview, autolayout, uinavigationbar

I'm trying to implement a notification bar which should appear below the `UINavigationBar`. The problem is that when the notification appears the cells in the `UITableView` are not pushed down and are therefore hidden behind the notification like this:

[image]

My code looks as follows:

```
@IBOutlet var notificationView: UIView!

let navBar = self.navigationController?.navigationBar
let navBarHeight = navBar?.frame.height
let notificationFrame = notificationView.frame
let nSetX = notificationFrame.origin.x
let nSetY = CGFloat(navBarHeight!)
let nSetWidth = self.view.frame.width
let nSetHight = notificationFrame.height

notificationView.frame = CGRect(x: nSetX, y: nSetY, width: nSetWidth, height: nSetHight)
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.addSubview(notificationView)
```

Comment: just update the tableview constraint for `top` or `tableView.frame.origin.y`

Comment: @h44f33z how would you go about this? `self.tableView.frame.origin.y = self.tableView.frame.origin.y + nSetHight` doesn't move it at all. And as far as i can tell you cannot set a top constraint for the tableview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few solutions for your problem, but maybe the easiest one for you could be adding a content offset on the top, like this:

```
self.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(newBar.height, 0, 0, 0)
```

Another solution as @h44f33z suggested is adding a constraint between the new bar and the tableView, so it would be similar to this (in visual format):

```
"V:|-0-[newBar(\(newBar.height))]-0-[tableView]-0-|"
```